# Primitive roots and quadratic residue classes

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p = 2q +1$ with $q$ prime. Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a \not\equiv0,\pm1 $(mod $p$). Prove that $a$ is a primitive root modulo p, iff $a$ is not a quadratric residue class modulo $p$.

How should i tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The multiplicative group mod $p$ has order $p-1 = 2q$, so anything not of order $1$, $2$ or $q$ must be a primitive root.